# Where is com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.jasperreports?

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports

Following information here:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-ultimate-guide/v55/report-data-source-service-api
and here:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/516771/bean-datasource-pass-parameter
Regarding the usage of the class: ReportDataSourceService for fetching the report's parameters.
I'm trying to find a JAR file which will contain this class. None of the Jasper JARs I found contained it. I'd appreciate to know where to find it.
Thanks

Comment: It part of the jasper report server not the distributed jasper report

Comment: Thanks Petter. Can you share a link to this JAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is in the jasper report server distribution, not in the regular jasper report distribution

[jasperreports-server/releases](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server/releases)

You will find it inside the war file `jasperserver.war\WEB-INF\lib\jasperserver-api-metadata-6.2.0.jar\`

Comment: I didn't manage yet to get everything working on my Jasper Server and IReports/Jasper Studio, but the Jar file was just where you pointed me to. Thanks Petter